# Browser back and forward buttons behave weird when using pjax in yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, query-string, pjax

I am using pjax in my gridview to not append search query parameters in url. Here is my code for view

```
 <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax_one',
                'timeout' => false,
                'enablePushState' => false, 
                'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'get']
                ]) ?>
            <?=
            GridView::widget([... rest code is here]);
            ?>
  <?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

In controller:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $searchModel = new UserSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    ]);
}
```

This code working fine. But using this code browser back and forward buttons behave weird, it redirect to some other page instead of previous page.

If I do `'enablePushState' => true,` then it append query parameters to the url, which I do not want to append for the security reason.

**Edit: This is happening when I am visiting any page using link or button available in gridview.**

Comment: please remove timeout

Comment: @ShringirajDewangan then it will append query parameter in url which I do not want.

Comment: @Mannay enablePushState is responsible for browser url

Comment: @ShringirajDewangan I removed timeout. but still when I click on any action button inside pjax gridview, it redirect to correct page, but when I click on browser back, It does not redirect to previous page still.